# Midband output voltage of cascode BJT amplifier in PSpice not right

Tags: bjt, pspice, cascode

I made a cascode BJT amplifier. \$V_{AC}\$  = 10e-3 V (ACMAG)

From an AC sweep at the output, \$R_L\$, I need to get a voltage between 200 mV and 250 mV. However, I got 0 V.

Why is this so? Do I need to change the biasing?

[image: schematics of cascode]

[image: AC result]

---

EDIT

\$R_L\$ = 1M was changed to

\$R_L\$ = 1Meg (instead of milli)

Should the gain be negative?

Comment: But the voltages values (in green) that you have shown us on your diagram is a DC voltage. Try to show us the AC sweep analysis results instead.

Comment: Also, try to change your BJT's model to Q2N2222. And set AC source to 1V

Comment: The C4 capacitor value is a way too small. In fact, all capacitor looks too small in value.

Comment: @G36 Thanks for replying. i cannot change the BJT model as it is required to be BC548B in the question. I did change the model. AC source is 10mV that is also question requirement. I changed the capacitor value to 1F. I also attached the AC sweep result in the question. However, it doesnt show that the output voltage is between 200mV and 250mV

Comment: Can you show us you AC sweep setup?

Comment: Type is linear, start frequency is 100k to 1000kHz, with 100pts

Comment: Why from 100k?  Try Octave 110 from 10 to 1000k

Comment: the output is still the same as previous

Comment: What type of an input source did you use?

Comment: I am using VAC with ACMAG = 10e-3

Comment: Please change ACMAG to 1V and place the voltage marker at the input. Do you see now 1V at the input?

Comment: Yes. The AC sweep results show 1V

Comment: Good so, now place the voltage marker at Q3 collector (AC --Octave 101 from 10 to 1000k)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83400/discussion-between-sterstar-and-g36).